# How do I have data manager tell View Controller to reload collection

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, asynchronous, singleton

Sorry if anything I say is completely wrong but I am new to swift.

I have a UIViewController that contains a uicollectionsview. I then have a data manager that gets json data from instagram and then parses it. What I want to know is how make the data manager tell the ViewController to reload the data in the collection view. Every time I have the data manager tell the ViewController to reload the data it gives me an error saying it's nil. I'm thinking its because the data manager was creating a brand new instance of the view controller so I used the singleton design patter to try and make it work. However, for some reason when I use .instance it crashes. I have that part commented out.

I also tried using threads to make it work but still no luck.

I know its not that there is no information because i have a button in the view controller that reloads the collection view when press and all the data is then loaded on to the collection view.

I've tried may other things as well and nothing is working.

below is the code for the ViewController:

```
class InstagramControllerView: UIViewController, MWPhotoBrowserDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate {
class var sharedInstance : InstagramControllerView {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0
        static var instance : InstagramControllerView? = nil
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        Static.instance = InstagramControllerView()
    }
    return Static.instance!
}

//OUTLETS
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

//let navigationController = InstagramNavigationController()

/* this will hold all of the information
** pertaining to this instagram account
*/
//let instagramHeader = InstagramHeader()
var nextUrl = ""

var dataManagerDone: Bool = false

let instagramDataManager = InstagramDataManager()

//arrays to hold instagram content
var headerResults: JSON?
var results: [JSON]? = []
var photos: [MWPhoto] = []
var thumbnailArr: [String] = []
var standardResArr: [String] = []
var descriptionArr: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
//    self.collectionView.reloadData()
//        let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
//        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0), {
//            self.instagramDataManager.getProfileInfoJson(self.profileUrlPath)
//            let thum = self.instagramDataManager.getImageDataJson(self.photoUrlPath)
//            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
//                    println("this is thumb \(thum)")
//                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
//                    println("i made it to view laod")
//            })
//        })
}

@IBAction func refresh(sender: UIButton) {
    self.refreshCollectionView()
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (bottomEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {
        instagramDataManager.getNextSetOfImages()
    }
}

func refreshCollectionView(){
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Now for the DataManager:

```
class InstagramDataManager {

var profilePictureURL: NSURL?
var postCount: String?
var followerCount: String?
var followingCount: String?
var username: String?
var bio: String?
var website: String?

var doneParsingProfile: Bool = false
var doneParsingImage: Bool = false

//arrays to hold instagram content
var results: [JSON]? = []
var thumbnailArr: [String] = []
var standardResArr: [MWPhoto] = []
var descriptionArr: [String] = []

let profileUrlPath = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/22755819/?access_token=fdasf"
let photoUrlPath = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/22755819/media/recent/?count=65&access_token=jdkfjs"
var nextUrl = ""

init(){
    self.getProfileInfoJson(profileUrlPath)
    self.getImageDataJson(photoUrlPath)
}

//returns true when done
func getProfileInfoJson(urlPath: String) -> Bool {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlPath).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
        if json != nil {
            var jsonObj = JSON(object: json!)
            self.parseProfileData(jsonObj)
        }
    }
    return true
}

//returns true when done
func getImageDataJson(urlPath: String){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlPath).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
        if json != nil{
            var jsonObj = JSON(object: json!)
            if let data = jsonObj["data"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {
                self.results? += data
                self.parseImageData(data)
            }
            if let paginationUrl = jsonObj["pagination"]["next_url"].stringValue? {
                self.nextUrl = paginationUrl
            }else{
                self.nextUrl = ""
            }
        }
    }
}

private func parseImageData(jsonData: [JSON]){
    for i in 0..<jsonData.count{
        if let thumbnail = jsonData[i]["images"]["thumbnail"]["url"].stringValue? {
            self.thumbnailArr.append(thumbnail)
        }
        if let standardResPhoto = jsonData[i]["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"].stringValue? {
            self.standardResArr.append(MWPhoto(URL: NSURL(string: standardResPhoto)))
        }
        if let description = jsonData[i]["caption"]["text"].stringValue? {
            self.standardResArr[i].caption = description
        }
    }
    self.doneParsingImage = true
    doneParsing()
}

private func parseProfileData(json: JSON){
    if let photoUrl = json["data"]["profile_picture"].stringValue? {
        self.profilePictureURL = NSURL(string: photoUrl)
    }
    if let postCount = json["data"]["counts"]["media"].stringValue? {
        self.postCount = postCount
    }
    if let follows = json["data"]["counts"]["follows"].stringValue? {
        self.followingCount = follows
    }
    if let followers = json["data"]["counts"]["followed_by"].stringValue? {
        self.followerCount = followers
    }
    if let username = json["data"]["username"].stringValue? {
        self.username = username
    }
    if let bio = json["data"]["bio"].stringValue? {
        self.bio = bio
    }
    if let website = json["data"]["website"].stringValue? {
        self.website = website
    }
    self.doneParsingProfile = true
    doneParsing()
}

//reload collection view once both image and profile have been parsed
private func doneParsing(){
    if self.doneParsingImage && self.doneParsingProfile {
        //InstagramControllerView.sharedInstance.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I've obviously left some code out that is unnecessary.

Any help I can get will be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: I do not see where `getNextSetOfImages()` is defined.

Comment: @Firo I left if out. it doesn't do anything until I reach the bottom of the scroll view. it's to load the next set of images

Comment: Why don't you just use the delegate pattern? so that your view controller will be the delegate of the datamanager ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically instead of attempting to get ahold of the collection view and refreshing it, you want your InstagramVC to give the DataManager a block to execute upon receiving data. This way any object can request Instagram data. The Instagram Manager should not be tied to any controller specifically. So to do this you first need to pass a code block upon requesting data:

```
func getImageDataJson(urlPath: String, completion: () -> ()) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlPath).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
        if json != nil {
            var jsonObj = JSON(object: json!)
            if let data = jsonObj["data"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {
                self.results? += data
                self.parseImageData(data)
            }

            // Not sure where you want this but let's just execute the block here
            completion()

            if let paginationUrl = jsonObj["pagination"]["next_url"].stringValue? {
                self.nextUrl = paginationUrl
            } else {
                self.nextUrl = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then when requesting data just pass in a fragment that you want to have executed once data is returned:

```
self.instagramDataManager.getProfileInfoJson(self.profileUrlPath) {
    // Upon completion of receiving data refresh my collection view
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

And you are done. Then **remove everything that has to do with a singleton!!!**

Comment: It worked!!! I did not know about the code block information. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Just really make sure to clean up that singleton code! You should not be using a singleton here at all.